# Discord.py on_member_update and messaging/dming channel/user

Tags: python-3.x

I'm having trouble messaging the server and dming the specific user who started playing a game. This is the current code:

```
    @bot.event
    async def on_member_update(before, after):

    game = [i for i in after.activities if str(i.type) == "ActivityType.playing"]
    if game:
    print(game[0].name)
    await member.send("you're playing a game")
    await message.channel.send({member} is playing game[0].name)
```

The print to console works but I'm getting errors stating to define member and message. How do I define them? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

u have to get attribute member to get that it is

```py
@bot.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):

    game = [i for i in after.activities if str(i.type) == "ActivityType.playing"]
    if game:
    print(game[0].name)
    await after.send("you're playing a game")
    await message.channel.send({member} is playing game[0].name)
```

so after is a member attribute, u can get more info in [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_member_update#discord.on_member_update)

Comment: Hmm it's still throwing an an error stating message is undefined. How would I define message if I'm defining on_member_update? OR would it simply be `await after.channel.send...`

Comment: it means the msg is empty means its like `send("")` which is invalid

Comment: What would then be the proper code to send to the channel that the specific user is playing a game? `await after.channel.send(" ")` ?

Comment: Yes, but the msg should not be empty

Comment: `message.channel.send` would not work because channel was not defined,. I solved it doing `channel = await bot.fetch_channel(####)` and then did `await channel.send(my message)`